# Reorder categories in x-axis of bar graph in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I wish to reorder the x-axis values. I mean, I need to reorder the Income group category as Rural first, Rural_connurbations second, uRBAN third and the Average or summaries should be the last one in the order.

[image]

I tried to do that using sort x-axis. But i find only ascending or descending order. How do i sort it on custom basis ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a new column with the desired numerical order and then sort your categorical field by that new numerical field.

Creating a new column can be done in a number of ways:

1. At the data source
2. In the Power Query editor (in a few ways depending on your model)
3. Using DAX formula

You can view the PBI documentation on sorting by another column [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column?tabs=powerbi-desktop). Here is a screenshot from the documentation showing the key step to sort by another column.

[image: PBI Documentation Screenshot]